# Generating subscriber keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, bestpractice, key

We have a master list of over 600,000 records in Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) that was not set up with a Subscriber Key. As we're planning on using SMS for some subscribers, we need to set up a unique subscriber key for everyone on the list. We don't have (and don't need) mobile numbers for everyone so that isn't an option.

As an added twist, we have 4 different platforms adding subscribers to the list.

Is there a way to generate a unique subscriber key automatically for new records, or will we need to create some sort of web service that generates a key and call that from each platform when adding a new record?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please specify what SFMC edition you use, how many Business units you use. Also do you have an integration with Sales/Service Cloud. The answer really depends on these details since strategies for different SFMC setups are different. Anyway, I would recommend to contact SFMC services (which is not free) and try to find a solution together.